# ¿Cómo puedo buscar un único valor dentro de un diccionario ? Python

Tags: python, diccionarios, buscador

Quiero buscar dentro de un diccionario y que solo me traiga el valor de la clave introducida... Este es el error

> TypeError: must be str, not dict

```
import interface as In

 

words={"Emberracarse ": "furious" , "Perico ": "parakeet","Sapo":"informer","Tombo" :"pólice", "Lucas ": "money", "Rumbiar" : "to dance","Ñero" : "delinquent", "Gamín" : "rude",
"Culicagao" : "child","Bizcocho" : "gorgeous"," Choro" : "robber","Calletano" : "reserved","Desparche" : "bored" , 
"Bagre" : "catfish","Desechable": "homeless","Chiviado" : "cheap copy","Abeja" : "crafty","Traga" : "in love","Recochar" : "bother",
 "Recochar" : "Joking" ,"Necio" : "foolish","Mecato" : "Candys", "Líchigo" : "Vegetables and fruits", "Hostigante" : "harassing","Jartera" : "nuisance",
 "Enguayabado" : "hangover","Cantaleta": "scold","Bacano" : "Cool","Amañado" : "Customary","Pana" : "corudoy","Parcero": "Friend"}





def buscar_palabras(self,palabras):
   word=words
   print(In.recibir_string("¿Que palabra deseas buscar?"))
   for clave, valor in words.items():
       if clave.find(words) != valor:
          word=valor
   In.imprimir(word)
```

Comment: No logro entender tu código. No tiene ni pies ni cabeza. Por favor, explicalo.

Comment: Ah, el error es porque `clave` es un string (una de las llaves del diccionario, como "Perico "). Por otra parte, `words` es un diccionario. No puedes buscar un diccionario dentro de un string. Tu código no tiene sentido.

Comment: No debería hacer solo `palabra =input(); word.get(palabra, None)`??

Answer (score 0):

El error que te muestra es por esto:
`if clave.find(words) != valor:`

Pero el código en sí es un poco raro.

Como no sé que hace el paquete `interface`  no entiendo como recoges los datos de entrada, imagino que será algo como `word = input()`

Recorrer el diccionario sería si buscases una clave en un diccionario, tu busqueda se resuelve simplemente con `resultado_busqueda = words.get(palabra_a_buscar, 'No la encuentro')`

Entiendo que `def buscar_palabras(self,palabras):` es un método de una clase y que *palabras* pretendía ser *words*, dado que luego no utilizas la variable *palabras*

Con `word=words` tienes 2 variables apuntando al mismo diccionario, cualquier cambio que haces en `word` lo harías también en `words`. Si quieres una copia del diccionario (aunque no creo que sea lo que pretendes) sería `palabras = words.copy()`. Ahora `palabras`y `words` aunque tienen el mismo valor son dos diccionarios diferentes.

El código (para una función, no un método) quedaría algo así:

```
def buscar_palabras(words):
   palabra = input("¿Que palabra deseas buscar?")
   print( words.get(palabra, 'No la encuentro'))
```

o así:

```
def buscar_palabras(words):
   print( words.get(input("¿Que palabra deseas buscar?"), 'No la encuentro'))
```

Comment: Por lo que ví en otra pregunta del OP, creo que `interface.recibir_string("bla bla bla")` (o bien `In.recibir_string("bla bla bla")`) devuelve una cadena resultante de un input con el texto `"bla bla bla"`. Así que podemos cambiar `input("¿Que palabra deseas buscar?")` por `In.recibir_string("¿Que palabra deseas buscar?")`.